# Selecting ASCII in Java

Tags: java, ascii, bufferedreader

Sending a URL POST and get the answer throughout BufferredReader the respond is coming in ASCII. How the incoming String can be break into pieces and only use the String I need?

```
    params.put("ssl_result_format", "ASCII");

    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));
    String line;
    Receipt pp = new Receipt();
    pp.setVisible(true);
    while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {       
    Receipt.receText.append(line + "\n");
    System.out.println(line);
```

This is how is display:

```
ssl_card_number=50**********3003
ssl_exp_date=1215
ssl_amount=12.00
ssl_invoice_number=
ssl_departure_date=
ssl_completion_date=
ssl_issue_points=
ssl_promo_code=
ssl_enrollment=
ssl_result=0
ssl_result_message=APPROVAL
ssl_txn_id=051214A15-6E33E984-7C6B-466D-B38C-83F24BDAC631  ETC......
```

EDIT: I FINISHED WITH THIS:

```
Properties prop = new Properties();        
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));
    prop.load(in);
    String amount = prop.getProperty("ssl_amount");
    String card = prop.getProperty("ssl_card_number");
    String approval = prop.getProperty("ssl_approval_code");
    String results = prop.getProperty("ssl_result_message");
    String time = prop.getProperty("ssl_txn_time");
    String errorCode = prop.getProperty("errorCode");
    String errorMessage = prop.getProperty("errorMessage");
    String errorName = prop.getProperty("errorName");        
    if(errorCode == null){
    Receipt pp = new Receipt();
    pp.setVisible(true);
    Receipt.amountLabel.setText(amount);
    Receipt.cardLabel.setText(card);
    Receipt.approvalLabel.setText(approval);
    Receipt.respondLabel.setText(results);
    Receipt.dateLabel.setText(time);
    }else{
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,errorName,errorMessage,JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            }
```

+1 to Crunchify.com

Comment: This question makes no sense to me.

Comment: I only need to print ssl_amount=12 and not the hole respond.

Comment: Use a properties file. See: http://crunchify.com/java-properties-file-how-to-read-config-properties-values-in-java/

Comment: ^^ Perfect.... crunchify work like I want to. I can give variable to each entry. flawless.

Answer (score 0):

In your while loop, check to see if the line starts with what you care about.  For example,

```
while ((line = in.readLine() != null) {
  if (line.startsWith("ssl_amount") {
    Receipt.receText.append(line + "\n");
    System.out.println(line);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use StringTokenizer to break the string and inspect the first part of the String, when you get what you want print out the value

```
params.put("ssl_result_format", "ASCII");

BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));
String line;
Receipt pp = new Receipt();
pp.setVisible(true);
while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {       
Receipt.receText.append(line + "\n");
StringTokenizer strToken = new StringTokenizer(line, "=");
if(strToken.hasMoreTokens() && strToken.nextToken().equals("ssl_amount"))
    System.out.println(strToken.nextToken());
```